# Magento 2 order update email message translation

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Magento 2 order update email message text "order status" pending etc... translation doesn't work but other email message text content is translated correctly. I have translated every "order status" using admin panel Stores/Order status. How to fix this issue?

Email template

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name" name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans
                    "Your order #%increment_id has been updated with a status of <strong>%order_status</strong>."

                    increment_id=$order.increment_id
                    order_status=$order.getStatusLabel()
                |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>{{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend comment}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var comment|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```